# Interleaving output from two different procedures with a by value

Tags: sas

I have a large SAS dataset and I would like to make a series of tables and charts using by value processing.  I am outputing these to a PDF.

Is there any way to get SAS to alternate between the table and the chart as it goes through the data?  Right now, I have to print all of the tables first and then print the charts.  If it were just 4 tables/charts, then I would be ok writing

Here is a simple example:

```
data sample;
  input byval $ item $ amount;
  datalines;
A X 15
A Y 16
A Z 12
B X 25
B Y 10
B Z 18
;
run;

symbol1 i=j;

proc print data=sample;
  by byval;
  var item amount;
run;

proc gplot uniform data=sample;
  by byval;
  plot amount*item;
run;
```

This prints 2 tables, followed by 2 charts.
I would like the Chart for "A" to come after the table for "A" so that the reader can flip through the pdf and always see the associated charts and tables together.

I could write separate procs for each one, but then the gplot won't have a uniform axis (and it gets messy if I have 100 different groups instead of 2).

I thought about pumping them into greplay but then you can't use titles with "#BYVAL1".

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but it may be worth checking out ODS DOCUMENT.  This allows you to store the output of all your procedures and then reference specific items from them using PROC DOCUMENT.

Below is a link to the SAS website with useful information about this, in particular the paper by Cynthia Zender for the SAS Global Forum 2009.

http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsdocument/index.html

Cynthia also regularly contributes to the SAS Support Communities website (https://communities.sas.com/community/support-communities), so it may be worth asking on there if you are still stuck.

Good luck

Comment: This looks very useful, I will investigate further.

Comment: Good idea - I used ODS DOCUMENT once and then promptly forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do what you ask directly.  GREPLAY is probably the closest you'll come; the primary problem is that SAS processes the PROCs linearly, first processing the entire PROC PRINT, then the entire PROC GPLOT.  GREPLAY would allow you to redisplay the output, but if that doesn't work for your needs due to the #BYVAL issue, I'm not sure there's a better solution.  Perhaps you can modify the title afterwards (not sure if GREPLAY allows this)?

You could try using ODS LAYOUT, but I don't think that would be any better.  The one way it *could* be better is if you can work out having two columns on a 'page', one column being the PROC PRINT outputs, one the PROC GPLOT, and then print the columns one page than the other.  I don't think this is possible, but it might be worth exploring.

You might also try setting up a macro to do each BYVAL separately, defining the axis in a uniform manner manually (ie, defining it based on your own calculation of the correct axis parameters, as an argument to the macro).  That is probably the easiest solution that might still allow #BYVAL to work properly.

You might also try browsing about Richard DeVenezia's site (http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/ ) which has a lot of examples of SAS/GRAPH solutions.  He also posts on SAS-L (sasl@listserv.uga.edu) sometimes, not sure if I've seen him on StackOverflow.  He's probably the person most likely to be able to answer the question that I know of.